# Sum of the four-momentums of the system: sum of norms or norm of the sum?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, energy-conservation

The observer is at rest at point O. At once, he shots two bullets with equal masses $m$ in the opposite directions. Their velocities are equal by modulo $v=v_1=-v_2$.
Now, he wants to calculate the total invariant mass of such a system.

The bullet's four-momentums are
$$p^{\mu}_1=\left(\frac{mc}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},0,0\right) \quad p^{\mu}_2=\left(\frac{mc}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},-\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},0,0\right)\tag{1}$$
Obviously, the sum of their norms gives the total rest mass as $$|p^{\mu}_1|+|p^{\mu}_1|=2mc^2\tag{2}$$
Where the norm is $|p|=\sqrt{-p \cdot p}$. The result seems to be obvious because it represents the initial summ of the rest masses of the bullets at point O.
However, if now one considers the system as whole, then adding four-momentums as 4-vectors results in
$$p^{\mu}=p^{\mu}_1+p^{\mu}_2=\left(\frac{2 mc}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},0,0,0\right)\tag{3}$$
which is the total four-momentum of the system. And therefore its norm is $$|p^{\mu}|=|p^{\mu}_1+p^{\mu}_2|=\frac{2mc}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\tag{4}$$
Which means that the system has greater mass comparing to (2).
Which of these two (2)/(4) is the correct one? I suspect that (2) is the correct. Because in the general case, (4) will depend on the directions at which bullets are shot.
Then, if (2) is the correct way, what's wrong with (4)? Why four-momentums can not be just added as 4-vectors?

Note: the related question is [two-4-momentum-vectors-before-and-after-pair-production](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189156/the-norm-of-the-vector-sum-of-two-4-momentum-vectors-before-and-after-pair-produ), but the answer is lengthy, so I lost its main point.

Comment: What you have discovered is that rest mass is not a conserved quantity in relativity. I think this has been asked before. I'll have a look now and see if I can find the previous references to this.

Comment: See for example: [Is (rest) mass conserved in special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175444/). The [answer by djbinder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/175451/1325) discusses exactly the situation you describe.

Comment: The rest mass should play the role of being invariant for 4-vector. The same as the interval for 4d Minkowski spacetime. I doubt that may change after all.

Comment: @John Rennie thanks! well, the answer votes for the way (4). And this is really strange I would say..changing the direction of shots one can change the total rest mass of the system then.

Comment: The point is that the rest mass of a system made up from multiple particles is not the same as the sum of the rest masses of the individual particles.

Comment: @John Rennie. This sounds logical. So I'm getting a bit clear on this..

Comment: Indeed, as in ordinary euclidean geometry, the magnitude of the vector-sum is not equal to the sum of vectors-magnitudes, since direction must be taken into account. There are many analogies (and contrasts) between Euclidean and Minkowskian geometry, which could aid in geometric and physical intuition. (Draw an energy-momentum diagram.)